# Embed full comments from Facebook post

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to embed a whole list of comments from a Facebook post into web page. I googled around but found that Facebook only supports embedding "single" comment.

For example, I create a post in my Facebook post and my friends comment on the posts. Now I want to embed all my friends' comments into my blog, without the post content.

Is this currently officially supported by Facebook? Or is there any 3rd party library can help to render the comments following Facebook UI style?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at "Comment Mirroring" with the Comments Plugin in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments

It may be what you need, but afaik it only works with Pages.

You could also use the graph api to read the comments, but that would only work one way (from the page to your website). Check out the API reference for more information about that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/comment/

**Edit: Comment Mirroring is deprecated now: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/**

Comment: thanks for suggestion. As you mentioned, I like to put the comments of post to my page, but do not want to host any comment platform. You can think of "referring" the comment thread from my page.

Comment: the comments plugin with mirroring is the only way to do that. you could use the graph api to read the comments, but that would only work one way (from the page to your website). check out the api reference for more information about that.

Comment: Comment mirroring is deprecated now https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/

Comment: thanx for the input, i will add it to my answer!

Comment: @Carl is there a supported alternative?

Comment: @Shovalt apparently not, the only alternative is to build it yourself.